# PC crashes when debugging Android device in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

About once or twice a day, my PC will crash. After a considerable amount of time of investigating and observing what events could be leading up to this, I'm fairly confident that it occurs if Eclipse is running, my device is attached to the computer and I've debugged my app at least once.

I'm at a loss as what it could be. Nothing gets stored in the OS event logs, so this is likely hardware related. Maybe something with the USB. It also seems to only happen if the device is connected to the USB port.

Any suggestions on how I can investigate this further? I tried updating my USB driver but the one from Huawei is the latest and it didn't help, even though there is a new version that ships with the Android SDK but it is not compatible with my device. Or is there something in the Eclipse ADT part that could be causing this?

Comment: Hmm maybe your pc just overheats/goes out of memory from the intensive task of debugging? Is it a fairly good one?

Comment: I use a temperature app to monitor my CPU and graphics chips but they show cool temperatures. It doesn't seem to crash "during" debugging but only *after* I've debugged. In fact, I can't even recall once where it crashed during debugging.

Comment: Hmm no idea :) You might want to ask your question at the xda forum instead, as this isn't really a programming problem.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem! Please let me know if you find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a number of things but am not sure whether any have helped. I'll know during the day whether the problem comes back. In the meantime, if you are experiencing this problem, try the following:

1. Update Eclipse to the latest version.
2. Run the Android SDK Manager and update anything that says a newer version exists.
3. If you installed the Google Plugin for Eclipse recently, uninstall it. Click Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details. Select Google Plugin for Eclipse and then uninstall it.
4. In a DOS window, run sfc /scannow. Do this three times rebooting your computer between each scan.
5. Scan your hard drives for adb.exe. There should only be one and it should be in the Android SDK folder. If there is an additional one from your device manufacturer, replace it with the Android one.
6. Download an older version of adb.exe and replace your current version (if it is older). You can download it at:

[platform-tools_r12-windows.zip](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r12-windows.zip)

Just make sure to backup your newest adb.exe. I suspect the newest adb.exe has a bug in it that causes it to write to non-executable memory when accessing a device over USB.

I'll add more suggestions here if the problem returns and I try out more things.

**UPDATE:**

I ran the Android SDK Manager and updated all packages to be their latest versions. I also did a factory reset on my device, giving it a clean slate. This alone may have cured the problem. The device was already somewhat low on memory. Perhaps the device's internal USB driver was crashing at some point and/or sending garbage data to the USB driver on the PC side which didn't know how to handle it correctly. Most USB drivers for the PC will be provided by the device manufacturer although Google does provide one but is limited to working with only a few devices. So far things seem to be running smoothly but will know within a day.

As a side effect, updating the SDK also seemed to correct a lot of the Aw, Snap I was getting in Google Chrome.

Comment: Whats your computer Configuration. Eclipse is a RAM Eater purely,...  Run eclipse alone if it crashes your pc try to upgrade your pc configurations

Comment: UPDATE: Problem eventually came back but it is clearly a problem with Huawei's USB driver when debugging.

Comment: @AndroidDev I think you should add your last comment/Update to the top of the solution. Many people skip over comments.